# What does fuzzy means in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am working a narrative which is told by a five year old girl, and somewhere she says "Momma will pluck me out of bed and feed me bacon. I want to ask out loud but my teeth are too fuzzy." I could not understand what fuzzy means in this context. It somehow prevents her to ask the question out loud.

Answer (score 3):

While it wouldn't truly cause one to go mute, the sensation of numbness (lack of sensation?) can be described as 'fuzzy'. Specifically, after receiving anesthetic injections for dental work, the general numbness in the mouth can make speaking a challenge. It's not difficult to imagine a child describing the local oral numbness as 'teeth' being 'fuzzy'.

Answer (score 3):

The larger phrase "but my teeth are too fuzzy" describes the half dream state feelings of the child. It captures the child's not quite wanting to be awake, perhaps in part because it would require giving up an imagined world where there is bacon and mama for a near certain less attractive reality. It's not meant to make literal sense.